# URL Rewritting in htcaccess

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I recently gone through a source code of php and found this code in .htaccess in root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ ?menu=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_.\[\]\(\)@$]+)/$ ?menu=users&user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_.\[\]\(\)@$]+)$ ?menu=users&user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^bans/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_.\[\]\(\)@$]+)/$ ?menu=bans&banuser=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^bans/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_.\[\]\(\)@$]+)$ ?menu=bans&banuser=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please,can someone explain me why it is written twice instead once?

Thanks.

Comment: Twice? One has a trailing slash, the other hasn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at those lines and compare them character-by-character you'll notice that "doubled" lines actually not identical. I assume that, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_.\[\]\(\)@$]+)/$ ?menu=users&user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_.\[\]\(\)@$]+)$ ?menu=users&user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

differ only by `/` character to take into account cases when one can query for `users/some_user/` and `users/someuser` (with or without trailing slash). This is common thing to take into account, although it might be addressed at different levels - webserver or framework ones (or even both).

According to RegExp rules, putting a `?` sign makes the preceding character optional, which allows you to replace those "duplicates" from above with e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_.\[\]\(\)@$]+)/?$ ?menu=users&user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which **should be** sufficient, but needs testing.